# Server error with next.js - FetchError: request to https://jsonkeeper.com/b/4G1G failed

Tags: reactjs, typescript, server, next.js

Trying to get json from a link and destructuring the data to use for the site.  I have a getStaticProps export function that strips the data then I want to pass it into my default Home function and map through it.  I have read about "rejectUnauthorised: false" but not sure if that is the fix.

If I click the link I get a ssl warning

```
    export default function Home({ exp }) {
    return (
        <div className="">
            <Head>
                <title>Main Site</title>
                <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
            </Head>
            <Header />
            <Banner />
            <main className="max-w-7xl mx-auto px-8 sm:px-16">
                <section className="pt-6">
                    <h2 className="text-4xl font-semibold pb-5">Explore Nearby</h2>
                    
                    {exp?.map((item) => (
                        <h1>{item.location}</h1>
                    ))}

                </section>
            </main>
        </div>
    );
}

export async function getStaticProps() {
    const exp = await fetch(
        'https://links.papareact.com/pyp'
    ).then((res) => res.json());
    return {
        props: {
            exp,
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally solved this issue.  I needed to enact "rejectUnauthorized: false" in my export async function as below along with a few other things.  But the code below did the trick.  Then passed "data" as my prop and used it in my mapping.

```
 export async function getStaticProps() {
    const res = await fetch('https://links.papareact.com/pyp', {
        agent: httpsAgent,
    });
    const data = await res.json();
    return {
        props: {
            data: data,
        },
    };
}
```